# JavaScript files not working on content page asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ckeditor

I have a content page where I want to add 2 external JavaScript files for ckeditor. Everything is working find when I try this on a separate .aspx page but when I try it on content page following javascript files are not working.

```
1: <script type="text/javascript" src="/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
2: <script type="text/javascript" src="/ckeditor/samples/js/sample.js"></script>
```

I have tried different solutions that are available still got no result.
I have tried adding these files in:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="Server">
```

I also tried:

```
<script src='<%=ResolveClientUrl("~/ckeditor/ckeditor.js") %>' type="text/javascript"></script>
```

But nothing is working for me. If i remove masterpage then it works fine but I want it working inside content. Is there a possible solution?

Comment: Unless your application is no longer running under the root of the domain, or the files have been moved, I can't see why the two original `<script>` lines would fail.

Comment: The question is, have you checked the console log in the developer tools?

Comment: In developer tools i'm getting this error: "Error code: editor-incorrect-element.". But in other page where its working fine I don't get this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comment by the OP...

> In developer tools i'm getting this error: "Error code: editor-incorrect-element.". But in other page where its working fine I don't get this error

In which case this is not a problem with the location of your JS files.

It is because when you move from a simple ASP.Net page to a MasterPage setup, the `id` of the rendered elements will change (for instance from `txtEditor` to `ctl00_txtEditor`) due to something called `Naming Containers`.

You need to make sure that your javascript is telling the ckeditor to use the correct element `id`... because at the moment your JS is giving it the wrong value

Comment: "You need to make sure that your javascript is telling the ckeditor to use the correct element id"... How can i do this?

Comment: In the code where you tell ckeditor which HTML element it should convert into an editor, change the `id` to the correct one for the element. Use your developer tools, inspect the textbox and find the `id` attribute. I've run out of time, will check back in later

Comment: As you told me "the id of the rendered elements will change" so I disabled that from web.config and my problem got solved. Thank you so much